# Zoom changed event for nokia Here maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm confused on how to handle zoom events with Nokia Here maps. Usually for example

```
map.addEventListener('dragend', function(){....})
```

why cant the same signature work for something like

```
map.addEventListener('zoomend', function(){....})
```

I know there is a event called `mapviewchangeend` but how will I use that to know if it was a zoom change rather a drag

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The supported map events are documented [here](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-mapevents-mapevents.html) , i think simplest way to achieve your requirement would be to check the map zoom level in the mapviewchangeend listener.

```
var oldZoom=map.getZoom();
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', function(){
     var newZoom=map.getZoom();
     if(newZoom > oldZoom){
      // zoomed in
     }else{
      // zoomed out
     }
     oldZoom=newZoom;
})
```

Comment: Actually, the mapviewchangeend event is not documented on the link. Worse even, the event is documented (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map.html#h-map__mapviewchangeend-event) only as a H.util.event without the actual properties the event exposes. Maybe someone could raise a bug?

Comment: Oh wow, I just realised that the documentation is correct. The event does not expose anything at all.