# There are no map type and zoom change event for Here maps. Are there any workarounds?

Tags: here-api

I've been unsuccessfully looking for a zoom change and a map type change events for a Here map project (web, js api): https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/events.html

I have found a workaround for the zoom change event here: [Zoom changed event for nokia Here maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142083/zoom-changed-event-for-nokia-here-maps)

But I couldn't find anything for a map type change. I can't even find any function like map.getMapType() or map.getScheme() which I could try to add to the previous workaround.

I'm using the basic ui control, so users can only switch between normal, satellite and terrain maps.

Does this event exist, and if not, if there a workaround as the one for the zoom change event?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 18 months I was confronted to this problem again and figured out a solution at last. Here it is:

```
map.addEventListener('baselayerchange', function(){
            var mapType = map.getBaseLayer().getProvider().copyrightKey_;
            if (mapType=="hybrid") {
                // case hybrid
                });
            }
            else if (mapType=="terrain") {
                // case terrain
                });
            }
            else {
               // case normal
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch a map type change by listening to the event "baselayerchange":

```
map.addEventListener('baselayerchange', () => {
  // ...
})
```

For detecting a zoom change, listening to "mapviewchangeend" as in the answer you're linking seems correct

```
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', () => {
   console.log(map.getZoom())
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can I get the type of map (normal, satellite or terrain) in the baselayerchange event?